# How do I call a function in my backbone.js view from my Openlayers event in that same view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers

Hopefully I am not too confusing here.  I have a Backbone.js application and using Openlayers together.

I have a VectorView.  And within that view I have a openlayers featuresAdded event.
Within that event I am trying to call another function in the view (geoquery).  The following below code isn't working.  Any ideas?

```
//event setup
this.layer.events.on({
"beforefeaturesadded": this.beforeFeaturesAdded,
"featuresadded": this.featuresAdded
});

featuresAdded: function(event){
    this.geoquery(polystring);      
},

geoquery: function(polystring){
}
```

Comment: I need to see more code to answer. This is going to be a context issue, you might try taking 'this' off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of the problem is is that OpenLayers is not setting the correct `this` context value for the callback function. When you register to the `featuresadded` event, you need to provide the scope value to `events.register`.

From OpenLayers [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Events-js.html#OpenLayers.Events.register):

```
register: function (type,obj,func,priority)
```

> When the event is triggered, the ‘func’ function will be called, in the context of ‘obj’.  Imagine we were to register an event, specifying an OpenLayers.Bounds Object as ‘obj’.  When the event is triggered, the context in the callback function will be our Bounds object.  This means that within our callback function, we can access the properties and methods of the Bounds object through the “this” variable.

So if you want the `this` scope to point to your view, you need to pass the view as the second argument. Assuming you're registering to the event from within the view:

```
layer.events.register('featuresadded', this, this.featuresAdded);
```

Or from outside of the view:

```
layer.events.register('featuresadded', view, view.featuresAdded);
```

Comment: @Seth, I'm afraid not. All the OpenLayers projects I've worked with are a bit too large to extract to a simple fiddle.

Comment: another issue im running into now that i added your fix.  I also have a mapview that creates this vectorview.  In my featuresAdded function above I was doing the following. var mapProjv = this.map.getProjectionObject();  This no longer works.  What do i have to do to get that to work as well?

Comment: @Seth, what's `this` supposed to be in `this.map...`? The layer?

Comment: the getProjectionObject() is a function in the Openlayers Map.  I am trying to call that from the featuresAdded event.  'this' is my VectorView.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @Seth I see. From the code you posted it looks like your view has a property `this.layer`? If so, you can access the `map` via the layer: `this.layer.map.getProjectionObject()`.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Keep up the good work.  It's hard finding much info on backbone.js and openlayers.